# Uniqueness of Uniformly Most Powerul Test from Neyman–Pearson lemma

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

I am wondering if the converse to this theorem is true, where the setting is that we're testing $H_0 \colon \theta = \theta_0$, $H_1 \colon \theta = \theta_1$ with $p_0$ and $p_1$ the respective density.

[image]

That is, if $\phi_1$  is a test such that it agrees with $\phi$(a likelihood ratio test that is the most powerful) on $B =$ { $x \colon p_1(x) \neq kp_0(x)$ } a.e. $\mu$, and it has the same $\alpha$ as $\phi$, then $\phi_1$ and $\phi$ has the same power.

The question is motivated by this.

[image]

The situation is that the likelihood ratio is a non-decreasing function of sufficient statistics $T$. Then we may consider the test with $\phi_1 = 1$ if $T > c$, $\phi_1 = 0$ if $T < c$ and $\phi_1 = \gamma$ set so that the level of the test is $\alpha$. This test agrees with the likelihood ratio test $\phi$ on {$x \colon p_1(x) \neq kp_0(x)$}, but not on its complement.

Does $\phi^*$ and $\phi$ have the same power?

Comment: @User1865345 basically, say you have likelihood ratio test $\phi$, and another test $\phi_1$. $\phi_1$ has the same level $\alpha$ as $\phi$, and $\phi_1$ agrees with $\phi$ for all $x$ such that $p_1(x) \neq kp_0(x)$. However, $\phi_1$ disagrees with $\phi$ for $x$ such that $p_1(x) = kp_0(x)$. Since the set where $\phi_1$ and $\phi$ disagree can have positive measure, is it possible that $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ have different power?

Comment: As $\varphi_1$ is the same as $\varphi$ in $p_1(x) \neq kp_0(x), $ the former is MP test - it follows from the sufficient and necessary conditions of NP lemma. In fact, the set in which they differ is used to make the test of exact size $\alpha.$